# .less mixin guard won't accept @media in expression

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I'm trying to create a mixin guard, as seen on http://lesscss.org/features/ , where they do `mixin(@a) when (@media = mobile) { ... }`

However, when I do `mixin() when (@media = mobile) { ... }` or `mixin(@a) when (@media = mobile) { ... }`, less is saying it's expecting a `)` at `@media`'s `@` sign and that it's expecting an "expression" at the closing `)`. Conversely, if I do `mixin(@a) when (@a = 5) { ... }`, less is happy.

Why is this, and how can I get @media to work in my mixin's guard?

Comment: Note that *just* `@media` thing is a variable having nothing to do with CSS `@media ...` statement (thus `@media = mobile` tries to compare `mobile` to the value of `@media` variable to be defined elsewhere). Aside of this, you seem to want to obtain current page media state missing the fact that Less is compiled to CSS *before* this CSS can/may be applied to any page (thus Less can have *no idea* what *will* be the media in a browser somewhere *in future*). In other words and in short: it's impossible.

Comment: I.e. in a *pre*processor, if you need different code for different media, the code should appear explicitly within the corresponding  `@media ... {...}` block.